# "for...of" loop on JSON response only shows first and last result

Tags: javascript, json, loops

Bare with me, still a js noob.

I'm doing a Fetch GET request to my database. JSON response is working to the console, I can see an array of 5 unique items. No console errors.

But rendering to the page I only get two items to display. Item 0 repeats 4 times and item 4 displays once. Odd. Something wrong with the way I'm using the "for...of"loop I guess, but I've pulled my hair out trying stuff and dunno what I'm doing.

Appreciate anyones help here.
Jobslist Dashboard Screenshot attached
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xb9Ra.jpg
[![dashboard][1]][1]

```
let url = new URL('//HIDDEN_URL_ENDPOINT');

async function getJobs() {
    let data;

    try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        data = await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error', error);
    }

    const jobContainer = document.getElementById("job_list");
    const jobRecords = data;

    for (const jobRecord of jobRecords) {

        const style = document.getElementById('sample_job')
        const job = style.cloneNode(true)
        job.setAttribute('id', 'nodeJobs');

        document.querySelector("#job_title").innerHTML = jobRecord.job_title;
        document.querySelector("#job_type").innerHTML = jobRecord.job_type;
        document.querySelector("#job_level").innerHTML = jobRecord.job_level;
        document.querySelector("#job_salary").innerHTML = jobRecord.job_salary;
        document.querySelector("#job_status").innerHTML = jobRecord.job_status;
        document.querySelector("#formated_date").innerHTML = jobRecord.formated_date;
        document.querySelector("#page_views").innerHTML = jobRecord.page_views;
        document.querySelector("#apply_clicks").innerHTML = jobRecord.apply_email_clicks;

        jobContainer.appendChild(job);
    }
}

getJobs();
```

Comment: First of all: indent your code properly. Aligning all lines to the same left margin makes the code hard to read (and debug).

Comment: I am also noob in JS, but I think let data and const jobRecords = data; is not the right way, Please check...I am also waiting for the right solution.

Comment: Element `id`s must be unique within a document. All your `document.querySelector()` will select the same element and overwrite the previous value with every iteration.

Comment: @Ivar ahh of course. How can I make #job_title_1, #job_title_2, #job_title_3 within the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that:

- `querySelector` will return the *first* match, so it will always find the *same* element in each iteration of the loop, and -- related --
- you generate HTML that has `id` attributes that are not unique (which is invalid in HTML)

So:

- Don't give the cloned elements an `id` attribute at all. You shouldn't need that. The original sample element could have one `id`, but remove it in the clone.
- Don't use `id` attributes in this template's inner structure at all, but use `class`  instead
- Make `querySelector` calls that start from the element that was just added, not `document`

Something like this (after you have adapted the HTML of `sample_job`):

```
    for (const jobRecord of jobRecords) {

        const style = document.getElementById('sample_job')
        const job = style.cloneNode(true)
        job.removeAttribute('id');

        job.querySelector(".job_title").innerHTML = jobRecord.job_title;
        job.querySelector(".job_type").innerHTML = jobRecord.job_type;
        job.querySelector(".job_level").innerHTML = jobRecord.job_level;
        job.querySelector(".job_salary").innerHTML = jobRecord.job_salary;
        job.querySelector(".job_status").innerHTML = jobRecord.job_status;     
        job.querySelector(".formated_date").innerHTML = jobRecord.formated_date;
        job.querySelector(".page_views").innerHTML = jobRecord.page_views;
        job.querySelector(".apply_clicks").innerHTML = jobRecord.apply_email_clicks;

        jobContainer.appendChild(job);
    }
```

The HTML wasn't provided, but the idea is something like this:

```html
<div id="sample_job">
    <div class="job_title"></div>
    <div class="job_type"></div>
    <!-- ...etc... -->
</div>
```

Comment: this makes sense (thankyou for the great explanation!)... however I've copied your code and am now getting this error. Same if I switch to .textContent

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')
    at getJobs

Comment: Make sure you didn't remove `id="sample_job"` from the HTML. That is the one `id` that should stay. Also make sure that all queries in `querySelector` have a match with `class` in your HTML (the error means one of them didn't). You can step through your code with a debugger (or use `console.log`) to spot which one is failing, and correct it. Your question didn't have HTML so I couldn't provide it in my answer. I added a simplified snippet.

Comment: thankyou, got it all working. really appreciate your time to help out a JS newbie. i've only been playing with JS for a month and long way to go but excited by what I've learned already. Stack Overflow is such an amazing community. Thank you again!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to replace `document` by your `job` element, and preferably replace all ids by classnames for example because the id  should be unique (and of course replace the `#` in the selector by `.` if you did so):

```
        job.querySelector("#job_title").innerHTML = jobRecord.job_title;
        job.querySelector("#job_type").innerHTML = jobRecord.job_type;
        job.querySelector("#job_level").innerHTML = jobRecord.job_level;
        job.querySelector("#job_salary").innerHTML = jobRecord.job_salary;
        job.querySelector("#job_status").innerHTML = jobRecord.job_status;
        job.querySelector("#formated_date").innerHTML = jobRecord.formated_date;
        job.querySelector("#page_views").innerHTML = jobRecord.page_views;
        job.querySelector("#apply_clicks").innerHTML = jobRecord.apply_email_clicks;
```